# Pluck in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I started reading about [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) today, it is a library for javascript that adds some functional programming goodies I'm used to using in Python. One pretty cool shorthand method is [pluck](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#pluck).

Indeed in Python I often need to pluck out some specific attribute, and end up doing this:

```
users = [{
    "name" : "Bemmu",
    "uid" : "297200003"
},
{
    "name" : "Zuck",
    "uid" : "4"
}]
uids = map(lambda x:x["uid"], users)
```

If the underscore shorthand is somewhere in Python, this would be possible:

```
uids = pluck(users, "uid")
```

**It's of course trivial to add, but is that in Python somewhere already?**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension in whatever function is consuming `uids`:

instead of

```
uids = map(operator.itemgetter("uid"), users)
foo(uids)
```

do

```
foo([x["uid"] for x in users])
```

If you just want `uids` to iterate over, you don't need to make a list -- use a generator instead. (Replace `[]` with `()`.)

---

For example:

```
def print_all(it):
    """ Trivial function."""
    for i in it:
        print i

print_all(x["uid"] for x in users)
```

Comment: One could use `x.get('uid', None)` (where `None` is the default) to avoid having an exception raised when the item does not have a uid.

Comment: print_all(x.uid for x in users) worked for me, with the answer's syntax I got an "object is not subscriptable" error.

Answer (score 16):

From **[funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy)** module (https://github.com/Suor/funcy) you can pick **pluck** function.

In this case, provided that funcy is available on your host, the following code should work as expected:

```
from funcy import pluck

users = [{
    "name" : "Bemmu",
    "uid" : "297200003"
},
{
    "name" : "Zuck",
    "uid" : "4"
}]

uids = pluck("uid", users)
```

Pay attention to the fact that the order of arguments is different from that used with underscore.js